# Transparent NSWindow can only be grabbed where pixels are

Tags: objective-c, transparency, customization, nswindow

I´m experimenting with custom NSWindow and got my first transparent custom window today.
Unfortunately I only can grab the window where pixels are visible. Is there a way to grab it anywhere inside the window bounds?

[image]

### Tia, Ronald

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would the user know where the bounds are?  Anyway, the solution is `[theWindow setIgnoresMouseEvents:NO]`.

Comment: I really understand your concerns. But this is purely experimental. I hope you understand. Thanks a lot for your hint.